# How can I configure firefox to open links in the same window, but requests from external applications in a new window?

Tags: firefox

I hate it, when sites decide for me, which links should open in a new window, and which in the same. The back-button doesn't work. Good thing is, firefox has the option `browser.link.open_newwindow`. If I set this to `1`, all links with `target=blank` open in the same window, as it should be. But now also clicks in external programs (like the email-client or newsreader) on links open this in the same window, destroying the already opened website. How can I configure firefox to open links in a website always in the same window, but in external programs opened URLs always in a new one?

Answer (score 2):

GoTo `about:config` and change

```
Browser.link.open_external = 2 or 3
```

to 1 instead of 2 or 3.
It worked for me on Firefox 64 (Linux Mint 19.1).

Answer (score 1):

In the config menu, set `browser.link.open_external` to 2.

[MozillaZine documentation](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_external)

EDIT: The above method only works for pre-3.5 versions of Firefox, and for SeaMonkey.  See also:
[advanced.system.supportDDEExec](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Advanced.system.supportDDEExec)
[Make Firefox open URLs passed from external applications in new tabs](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Make_Firefox_open_URLs_passed_from_external_applications_in_new_tabs)
 [Bug 172962 -  Options for where to open URLs from other applications (reuse tab, new tab, new window)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=172962)

Comment: That doesn't work. URLs from external applications are opened in the same window.

Comment: Are you using Firefox 3.5 or later?  The option was removed in 3.5.

Comment: Yes, I use 3.5.8 that is delivered with Ubuntu 9.10.

Comment: Were any of my edits helpful to you, or are you still having no luck?

Comment: It seems firefox has regressed on this issue. All the edits are non-working solutions for the most recent firefox version at time of writing (6.0.1)

Comment: That's disappointing, but not entirely unexpected. The recent Firefoxes (4, 5 and 6) are a bit different than the 3.5/3.6 family.